# www.domain works but https://domain not working in heroku

Tags: heroku, https, namecheap

Using Heroku (with ssl) and namecheap, not sure what exactly should i set to make https://domain work as well and have www.domain redirects to https connection.

Two things:

- www.domain works but goes to unsecured connection without https.
- http://domain also works and goes into secured connection with https.

Comment: You need to provide more information. E.g. what are your redirects, records, routes on your DNS provider? On your deployed Heroku app what have you done to point towards your DNS? CNAME?

Comment: I have: CNAME record with Host: www and value of what heroku gave. I also have a redirect with Host: @ and value of my https:// domain . com. On heroku i register www . domain . com and put the value in the cname at namecheap